# Enumerating array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have array of objects and some objects in it have the same value(for example user's guid).

I want find all object with same guide and remove all of then rather then first.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: sorry, you opened a question and received answers. Can you give us a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSMUtableArray's removeObject method. Notice that your object should implement the isEqual method appropriately.

[[NSMutableArray removeObject]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObject%3a)

as per the description:

> This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes
>   them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, **matches are determined on
>   the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message**. If the
>   array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect (although it
>   does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all you array need to be mutable `NSMutableArray`, then the process is:

- consider the **actual object**;
- check if **is present another object equal to this in the other objects**;
- if yes, **delete the equal objects include the actual**.

-

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@1, @2, @3, @2, @5, @3]];

for(int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
    id obj = arr[i];
    if([arr indexOfObject:obj inRange:NSMakeRange(i+1, [arr count]-i-1)] != NSNotFound) {
        [arr removeObject:obj inRange:NSMakeRange(i, [arr count]-i)];
        i--;
    }
}
```